# number of words in a corpus

Tags: r, text-mining

I am looking for a way to find the most frequent words in a text and I am using R.
by most frequent, I mean words which their low frequency are 1% of the words in the corpus. So I need to calculate the number of words in a corpus.

Here is my code, so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library('tm')
library('wordcloud')
library('RColorBrewer')
twittercorpus <- system.file("stream","~/txt", package = "tm")
twittercorpus <- Corpus(DirSource("~/txt"),
                        readerControl=list(languageEl = "en"))
twittercorpus <- tm_map(twittercorpus, removeNumbers)
twittercorpus <- tm_map(twittercorpus,tolower)
twittercorpus <- tm_map(twittercorpus,removePunctuation)
my_stopwords <- c(stopwords("SMART"))
twittercorpus <-tm_map(twittercorpus,removeWords,my_stopwords)
mydata.dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(twittercorpus)
```

I need something like:

```
freqmatrix <-findFreqTerms(mydata.dtm, lowfreq=rowSums(mydata.dtm)/100)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you look at `str(mydata.dtm)` there is a named  component called `nrow`.  Use that:

```
freqmatrix <- findFreqTerms(mydata.dtm, lowfreq=mydata.dtm$nrow/100)
```